# Create an ActionLink with HTML elements in the link text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

In an ASP.NET MVC view I'd like to include a link of the form:

```
<a href="blah">Link text <span>with further descriptive text</span></a>
```

Trying to include the `<span>` element in the `linkText` field of a call to `Html.ActionLink()` ends up with it being encoded (as would be expected).

Are there any recommended ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use Url.Action to build the link for you:

```
<a href="<% =Url.Action("Action", "Controller")%>">link text <span>with further blablah</span></a>
```

or use Html.BuildUrlFromExpression:

```
<a href="<% =Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<Controller>(c => c.Action()) %>">text <span>text</span></a>
```

Comment: Should be noted that `Html.BuildUrlFromExpression` is currently in the MVC Futures assembly and therefore not available in a standard install of the Beta.

Answer (score 42):

if you like using Razor, this should work:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">link text <span>with further blablah</span></a>
```

Comment: this is obviously a much more recent answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to render your action link to an MvcHtmlString as per normal, using either HTML.ActionLink, or Ajax.ActionLink (depending on your context), then write a class that takes the rendered MvcHtmlString and hacks your html link text directly into the already rendered MvcHtmlString, and returns another MvcHtmlString.

So this is the class that does that:  [please note that the insertion/substitution code is VERY simple, and you may need to beef it up to handle more nested html]

```
namespace Bonk.Framework
{
    public class CustomHTML
    {
        static public MvcHtmlString AddLinkText(MvcHtmlString htmlString, string linkText)
        {
            string raw = htmlString.ToString();

            string left = raw.Substring(0, raw.IndexOf(">") + 1);
            string right = raw.Substring(raw.LastIndexOf("<"));

            string composed = left + linkText + right;

            return new MvcHtmlString(composed);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would use it in the view like this:

```
@Bonk.Framework.CustomHTML.AddLinkText(Ajax.ActionLink("text to be replaced", "DeleteNotificationCorporateRecipient"), @"Link text <span>with further descriptive text</span>")
```

This approach has the advantage of not having to reproduce/understand the tag-rendering process.