# How do I use Jquery UI Tabs constructor methods?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using Asp.net MVC and I been trying to use Ajax UI tabs in jquery.

On the demo site: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

It has this

> Fetch external content via Ajax for
>   the tabs by setting an href value in
>   the tab links. While the Ajax request
>   is waiting for a response, the tab
>   label changes to say "Loading...",
>   then returns to the normal label once
>   loaded.

I never see the tabs change to loading in their demo. So I decided to try to make my own example.In my asp.net mvc application I set a href to a action view that loads up a partial view. In this action view I put a sleep thread of "5000".

Yet I never see this "loading...." they talk about, even with me slowing down the request and checking.

I then was looking at the constructor methods and I don't get how to use them for instance I was looking at the spinner option it has

> ## spinner
>
> Type:
>       String Default:
>       '*Loading…*'
>
> The HTML content of this string is
>   shown in a tab title while remote
>   content is loading. Pass in empty
>   string to deactivate that behavior.
>   Code examples
>
> Initialize a tabs with the spinner
>   option specified.
>
> ```
> $('.selector').tabs({ spinner: 'Retrieving data...' });
> ```
>
> Get or set the spinner option, after
>   init.
>
> ```
> //getter
> var spinner = $('.selector').tabs('option',
> ```
>
> 'spinner');
>       //setter
>       $('.selector').tabs('option', 'spinner', 'Retrieving data...');

So I did what was said and I put that line in my jquery and changed it to the real div that I have.

I don't see this spinner either so I don't know what I am missing. Do I have to do something else?

My JavaScript code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../images/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            // Tabs
        $('#tabs').tabs({ spinner: 'Retrieving data...' });


        });
        </script>
```

Edit

Thanks to "redSquares" post I now know why mine is not working but I use Html.ActionLink. So how can I form my Html.ActionLink to have the span tag? Or do I have to make my own Html helper?

Comment: That is a new question:) It would be better to accept this answer and ask a new question. Helps people who search this site and via google find the correct information

Comment: But to answer the next question look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402605/create-an-actionlink-with-html-elements-in-the-link-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put that spinner part wherever you're first starting tabs, probably in your document ready function. Put { spinner: 'Retrieving data...' } inside of the tabs.tabs(x).

Most times it will load so fast you won't see it, and that's a good problem to have.

You can see an example of this in action at [sneakyness.com](http://www.sneakyness.com), my current project

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a span within the anchor. Nice of the docs to explain this!

e.g

```
<ul>
  <li><span><a href="someUrl"><span>Spinner Needs this</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="shomeUrl1"><span>Spinner Needs this</span></a></li>      
</ul>
```

Demo [here](http://pastebin.me/d4d3fa70a6a3629dc88f51ffaa0d72ff)