# ASP.NET MVC creating an Ajax.ActionLink that is an image and text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm building a project with ASP.NET MVC2 and i have a problem. According to the application GUI design, I have a menu that should be generated to be like that:

```
<ul id="toc">
                <li><a href="A.html"><img src="img/green_led.png" width="17px" /> Page (A)</a></li>
                <li><a href="B.html"><img src="img/yellow_led.png" width="17px" /> Page (B)</a></li>
                <li><a href="C.html"><img src="img/red_led.png" width="17px" /> Page (C)</a></li>
                <li><a href="D.html"><img src="img/red_led.png" width="17px" /> Page (D)</a></li>
```

In oder to generate those links, I use Ajax.ActionLink to generate the links, but it generates the menu like this

```
<ul id="toc">

                <li><a href="A.html"> Page (A)</a><img src="img/green_led.png" width="17px" /></li>
                <li><a href="B.html"> Page (B)</a><img src="img/yellow_led.png" width="17px"/></li>
                <li><a href="C.html"> Page (C)</a><img src="img/red_led.png" width="17px"/></li>
                <li><a href="D.html"> Page (D)</a><img src="img/red_led.png" width="17px" /></li>
```

as u can notice the image is generated after the anchor tag not inside it.

Any suggestions to solve this isue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is solution [Create an ActionLink with HTML elements in the link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402605/create-an-actionlink-with-html-elements-in-the-link-text)