# a href and html.actionlink size not same

Tags: css, href, html.actionlink

If i use below , button display bigger.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add</a>
```

If i use below , button display smaller than above code.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "xx", "Law", new { _lawfileid = -1, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary icon-plus" })
```

How can i change Html.Actionlink like a href i ?

What is difference between actionlink and href or how can i set same size for both ?

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor

Comment: @Gaurav my question about size problem between 2 elements

Comment: okies, I get it. My glitch.

Comment: They are not the same, the first one has an i element in it and the second one has an extra class.

Comment: how can i change my actionlink according to a href and i ? if you can post answer i will accept best answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is that in the first line of code  you have an element  inside another element. Whereas in the second line of code you have a single element with extra class.

Similar question is already answered on stackoverflow. Please find the link below

[Create an ActionLink with HTML elements in the link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402605/create-an-actionlink-with-html-elements-in-the-link-text)

Since you need to build an element inside an element use @Url.Action as mentioned in the above link.