# Is there a way to give a Model.Example it's own class in linkText?

Tags: c#, class, model-view-controller, html.actionlink

I have an Anchor button with info of the link and a model that generates a count. I need the link to be one color and the Model.Example to be a different color. Is this possible?

Please see code example.

Link in .cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Example LinkText - (" + Model.Example + ")", "Example actionName", "Example controllerName", new { Model.ExampleID }, new { @class = "btn btn-add" })
```

Controller

```
public string Example => Count > 0 ? Count.ToString() : "";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402605/create-an-actionlink-with-html-elements-in-the-link-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own link with a different color inside the link:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Example actionName")'>Example LinkText - (<span class='some-class'>@Model.Example</span>)</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Staufcik